# Imperative with masu stem

Tags: grammar, imperatives

I just had my first karate lesson and was puzzled. When the instructor wanted us to start or stop he would say はじめ and やめ. I would have expected to hear はじめろ or はじめて for example.

Is it proper grammar to make an imperative from the masu stem or is this just a quirk of karate teachers?